# Transmitter and receiver precision

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, radio-frequency

How precise can we make a transmitter's signal and then detect signals? 
... And if different parts of the spectrum have different limits.

Answer (score 1):

To expand.

The issue is technically called synchronizing the transmitter and receiver. First you must sync that they are close enough in freq (within the BW of the receiver), next sync in phase if you are detecting coherently (eg, PSK, within maybe 10 or so electrical degrees, maybe more or less. Depends on your phase lock circuit). Finally your circuits have to frame and word sync if digital, that's usually the least constraining, but if you are transmitting data at Gbps rates clearly you need under 1 nsec. So, it depends on the freqs you use, the modulation, and the data rates.

That will determine what kind of clocks you need.